# How to create a variable based on a group variable, ranking variable and a value variable in stata

Tags: stata

I have a group variable, A, within group ranking variable, B, and a value variable, C. I need to create a new variable, D, for each group, based on the value of variable C when the within group ranking variable B has a value of one. The programming language is Stata. The desirable output for D should look like below.

```
A        B         C          D
Ryan     1         1          1
Ryan     2         0          1
Meg      1         0          0
Meg      2         1          0
```

Comment: Good questions here show **some** attempt at code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my guess at what you want:

```
clear 
input str4 A        B         C          wanted 
Ryan                1         1          1
Ryan                2         0          1
Meg                 1         0          0
Meg                 2         1          0
end 
egen D = total(C / (B == 1)), by(A) 
assert D == wanted
```

For discussion of principles, see [here](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0055), especially Section 10.